# An adverb for harming when it is serious and severe?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

> This drug would ----- harm kidneys.

I mean really badly seriously harming it. What adverb is the most idiomatic?

Comment: If you say that's serious and severe, then seriously and severely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word *seriously* is a good choice. Seriously (pun intended).

> This drug would seriously harm kidneys.

Compare the definition of [serious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serious)

> 4 b : having important or dangerous possible consequences
>   // a *serious* injury

and [severe](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/severe)

> 6 b : very painful or harmful
>   // a *severe* wound

(sources: Merriam Webster)

There isn't that much difference between them.

Comment: What about "irreversibly"?

Comment: That would imply the damage can't be repaired/treated. That will often be the case but it means something different; damage can be severe but reversible, and not severe but irreversible.